# API to collect public IP addresses of Oracle Cloud

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure, oracle-cloud-infrastructure-classic

I need the list of public IP addresses in an Oracle Cloud Account, what's the REST API to collect this information?

Answer (score 2):

For Oracle Cloud Infrastructure, you can list the public IPs for a given compartment using [this](https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/api/#/en/iaas/20160918/PublicIp/ListPublicIps) API.